# Error in installing the mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error while installing the mongodb on my windows7 system.

C:>mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
Sun May 12 16:19:51.162 [initandlisten]
Sun May 12 16:19:51.162 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary
.
Sun May 12 16:19:51.163 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to le
ss than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Sun May 12 16:19:51.163 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults t
o off for 32 bit and is currently off.
Sun May 12 16:19:51.163 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
Sun May 12 16:19:51.164 [initandlisten]

I didn't find any solution for this. Any help? Thank you

Comment: what error you are getting here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your error?It's just a warning that you shouldn't use Mongo on 32-bit machines because then the limit of storage size is 2 GB. Just read the article in the link you already have.